# WebStorm slow navigation to reference when using Flow as a JavaScript language

Tags: webstorm, static-analysis

While using [Flow](https://github.com/facebook/flow) as a project language, pressing <kbd>⌘+click</kbd> to navigate to reference takes around 4 seconds. This happens only when the  "Navigation, code completion and type hinting" checkbox is checked.

Is there a way to reduce that time or disable navigation by Flow while keeping code completion?

[image: WebStorm]

Comment: no, not possible.. Please feel free to file a request for this feature to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB. BTW, what WebStorm version do you work with? Navigation performance when using Flow service has been improved in 2018.2 (as compared with previous versions). Still not great, but much better...

Comment: Thank you Lena, I am using 2018.2. I use the navigation feature a lot and this makes using flow with Webstorm a burden. Moreover - it doesn't seem to learn, if you press twice on the same reference - it will take 4-5 seconds each time. I have followed your recommendation: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34331